# Datatreeview did not display the results

Tags: c#, winforms, objectlistview

Code:

```
dataTreeListView1.DataSource = model.Models;
dataTreeListView1.RootKeyValueString = model.Models[0].Guid;
dataTreeListView1.KeyAspectName = "guid";            
dataTreeListView1.ParentKeyAspectName = "partent_guid";
```

After running, datatreeview, display the Column name, but no content.

Comment: Maybe `KeyAspectName` and `ParentKeyAspectName` are case sensitive? You have "guid" while your property is "Guid".

Comment: Thank you very much, I tried a lot of ways, I did not think so simple.

Comment: Why this code does not work?

Comment: dataTreeListView1.ShowKeyColumns = false;